# Using Wildfly 8 from Eclipse

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, wildfly

I am trying to set up Eclipse with Wildfly 8 properly on my Linux box. Both Eclipse and Wildfly come from the package manager, hence they are located in `/usr` instead of my home dir. The problem is, that when I run Eclipse as my user, Eclipse has permissions issues with the Wildfly server, so I can't start it or deploy anything on it.

I looked for solutions online, and I found this thread: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/8892. The mentioned `jboss-as-cp` is now called `wildfly-cp`, and it can be used to move the server configuration to another directory, in this case into my home dir.

I did this, but now I don't know what's next. In the linked thread, it says, that I should point Eclipse to this dir, but how?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the server home directory in your Eclipse preferences:

```
Window | Preferences | Server | Runtime Environment
```

Select Wildfly 8.0 Runtime and click Edit, enter the directory populated by the `wildfly-cp` script as Home directory.

If that does not work, try adding a symlink to the `modules` directory of the real installation directory.

Comment: Well, I did this, it complains about the missing `jboss-modules.jar`. I have tried adding it with symlink (also the modules dir), but then it complains about the missing standalone.xml and others.

Comment: update: I managed to start JBoss using the `standalone.sh` in the bin folder, after copying the config files manually. But I want to use it from Eclipse, instead of running it externally.